An Old movie about a family in a virtual reality game
I'm trying to find an old movie. We had it once, but I can't seem to find the disks anymore.
I'm pretty sure it's name contained 3D on its own, however that isn't going to do much. It isn't that old, so nothing from the 1940s. 
The only key elements I can remember are the following:

The main characters were a family, so a grandfather (I'm not sure about a grandmother though), parents and two children, boy and girl. They are teenager-old, and the two of them were the ones originally intended to do the 'Test'.
The grandfather had to sit in a wheelchair in the real world, not in the VR
The majority of the movie happened inside a virtual reality, where the "players" (I think they were even called players) had to go through multiple levels. I have no clue left of the reason they had to do this, nor what the contents of the levels really were. However, I think that every family member (I'm sure about the grandfather, because I remember him being able to walk normally inside the VR) had a level where they could "shine".
There were two "pets" that main-boy kept. I'm not sure, but I think they were small, about 1.5 palms in size, and either sentient mechanical robots or some alien stuff.

I hope the provided information will lead to the discovery of the movie.

Sounds like you're describing Spy Kids 3-D: Game Over
From IMDb

Carmen's caught in a virtual reality game designed by the Kids' new
  nemesis, the Toymaker (Stallone). It's up to Juni to save his sister,
  and ultimately the world.


Yes, that was exactly it. Thank you. (For whatever reason people downvoted)

Its always better to elaborate you answer with plot, trailer  and other details.
